# What to do with repeated content (anchor text) in internal search results when it comes to SEO?

Tags: seo, links, html5, markup

On a website that delivers internal search results for products, within the results listing we have a repeating link to "add to favourites" (not browser-bookmarks, but user profile related) in every single search result.
Now I've been told from a SEO perspective it would be better to hide this anchor text, since it's repeating the same text for every result item (this could be done for example with "content"-css).
Yet I don't appreciate hiding content just from search engines. Especially with HTML5, wouldn't there be a much better solution to this, like somehow semantically telling the search engine that it's ok to repeat this content since it's part of a list of search results? I'm (not yet) a SEO pro, but as a frontend developer I'd like to be prepared for a discussion on this matter.

Comment: Btw, using a "button" instead of an anchor tag would not do the job, since this "add to favs"-functionality is a real link, so it works even without javascript.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming those search results are available to be crawled by search engines as their support for form submissions is very limited at best, repeating that text isn't going to hurt your SEO efforts at all. Text repeated in that manner is perfectly normal and common. I wouldn't change how you are doing or or worry about this at all.